# Как посчитать общую массу компьютера?

Tags: java

Я только начинаю, просто без понятия как это реализовать ...

```
public class Computer {
    public Processor processor;
    public Memory memory;
    public Storage storage;
    public Screen screen;
    public Keyboard keyboard;
    public String vendor;
    public String name;
    public double weightComputer;

    public Computer(Processor processor, Memory memory, Storage storage, Screen screen, Keyboard keyboard, String vendor, String name) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.memory = memory;
        this.storage = storage;
        this.screen = screen;
        this.keyboard = keyboard;
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double weight(double weightComputer) {
        weightComputer = processor.getProcessorWeight() + memory.getMemoryWeight() + storage.getStorageWeight() + screen.getScreenWeight() + keyboard.getKeyboardWeight() ;
        return 0;
    }
    public double getWeightComputer() {
        return weightComputer;
    }

    public String getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Processor getProcessor() {
        return processor;
    }

    public void setProcessor(Processor processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public Memory getMemory() {
        return memory;
    }

    public void setMemory(Memory memory) {
        this.memory = memory;
    }

    public Storage getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }

    public void setStorage(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public Screen getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }

    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Keyboard getKeyboard() {
        return keyboard;
    }

    public void setKeyboard(Keyboard keyboard) {
        this.keyboard = keyboard;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "\n" + "Производитель компьютера: " + vendor +
                "\n" + "Название компьютера: " + name + "\n" + "------------------------------------" + "\n" +
                "\n" + "Процессор" + "\n" + "------------------------------------" + processor +
                "\n" + "Оперативная память"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + memory +
                "\n" + "Накопитель информации"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + storage +
                "\n" + "Монитор"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + screen +
                "\n" + "Клавиатура"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + keyboard +
                "\n" + "Общая масса компьютера: " + weightComputer + "\n";
    }
}


public class Processor {
    public final double frequency;
    public final int numberCores;
    public final String manufacturer;
    public final double processorWeight;

    public Processor(double frequency, int numberCores, ProcessorManufacturer manufacturer, double processorWeight) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.numberCores = numberCores;
        this.manufacturer = String.valueOf(manufacturer);
        this.processorWeight = processorWeight;
    }

    public double getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public int getNumberCores() {
        return numberCores;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public double getProcessorWeight() {
        return processorWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Базовая частота процессора: " + frequency + "ГГц" +
                "\n" + "Общее количество ядер: " + numberCores +
                "\n" + "Производитель: " + manufacturer +
                "\n" + "Вес: " + processorWeight + " грамм" + "\n";
    }
}

public class Memory {
    public final String memoryType;
    public final int memoryVolume;
    public final double memoryWeight;

    public Memory(MemoryType memoryType, int memoryVolume, double memoryWeight) {
        this.memoryType = String.valueOf(memoryType);
        this.memoryVolume = memoryVolume;
        this.memoryWeight = memoryWeight;
    }

    public String getMemoryType() {
        return memoryType;
    }

    public int getMemoryVolume() {
        return memoryVolume;
    }

    public double getMemoryWeight() {
        return memoryWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Тип оперативной памяти: " + memoryType +
                "\n" + "Объем оперативной памяти: " + memoryVolume + " Гб" +
                "\n" + "Вес оперативной памяти: " + memoryWeight + " грамм" + "\n";
    }
}

public class Storage {
    public final String storageType;
    public final int  storageVolume;
    public final double storageWeight;

    public Storage(StorageType storageType, int storageVolume, double storageWeight) {
        this.storageType = String.valueOf(storageType);
        this.storageVolume = storageVolume;
        this.storageWeight = storageWeight;
    }

    public String getStorageType() {
        return storageType;
    }

    public int getStorageVolume() {
        return storageVolume;
    }

    public double getStorageWeight() {
        return storageWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Тип накопителя: " + storageType +
                "\n" + "Объем накопителя: " + storageVolume + " Гб" +
                "\n" + "Вес накопителя: " + storageWeight + " грамм" + "\n";
    }
}

public class Screen {
    public final double diagonal;
    public final String screenType;
    public final double screenWeight;

    public Screen(double diagonal, ScreenType screenType, double screenWeight) {
        this.diagonal = diagonal;
        this.screenType = String.valueOf(screenType);
        this.screenWeight = screenWeight;
    }

    public double getDiagonal() {
        return diagonal;
    }

    public String getScreenType() {
        return screenType;
    }

    public double getScreenWeight() {
        return screenWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Диагональ монитора: " + diagonal + "\"" +
                "\n" + "Тип матрицы монитора: " + screenType +
                "\n" + "Вес монитора: " + screenWeight + " кг" +"\n";
    }
}

public class Keyboard {
    private final String keyboardType;
    private final boolean illumination;
    private final double keyboardWeight;

    public Keyboard(KeyboardType keyboardType, boolean illumination, double keyboardWeight) {
        this.keyboardType = String.valueOf(keyboardType);
        this.illumination = illumination;
        this.keyboardWeight = keyboardWeight;
    }

    public String getKeyboardType() {
        return keyboardType;
    }

    public boolean isIllumination() {
        return illumination;
    }

    public double getKeyboardWeight() {
        return keyboardWeight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + "Тип клавиатуры: " + keyboardType +
                "\n" + "Подсветка клавиш: " + illumination +
                "\n" + "Вес клавиатуры: " + keyboardWeight + " грамм" + "\n";
    }
}

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Computer computer1 = new Computer(new Processor(3.5, 4, ProcessorManufacturer.INTEL, 120),
                new Memory(MemoryType.DDR4, 8, 120),
                new Storage(StorageType.HDD, 512, 130),
                new Screen(21.5, ScreenType.VA, 8),
                new Keyboard(KeyboardType.ОПТОМЕХАНИЧЕСКАЯ, true, 750), "Alienware", "Alienware TURBO");

        Computer computer2 = new Computer(new Processor(4.8, 8, ProcessorManufacturer.AMD, 100),
                new Memory(MemoryType.DDR3, 4, 100),
                new Storage(StorageType.SSD, 256, 100),
                new Screen(23.8, ScreenType.TN, 5),
                new Keyboard(KeyboardType.МЕМБРАННАЯ, false, 700), "MSI", "MSI Trident");

        Computer computer3 = new Computer(new Processor(5.4, 12, ProcessorManufacturer.INTEL, 200),
                new Memory(MemoryType.DDR5, 32, 200),
                new Storage(StorageType.SSD, 1024, 250),
                new Screen(32, ScreenType.IPS, 10),
                new Keyboard(KeyboardType.МЕХАНИЧЕСКАЯ, true, 900), "Lenovo", "Lenovo ThinkStation");

        System.out.println("В нашем магазине на данный момент представлено 3 компьютера: Alienware TURBO, MSI Trident, Lenovo ThinkStation.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Выберите, какие характеристики подходят вам из представленных компьютеров." + computer1 + computer2 + computer3);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Введите компьютер который выбрали: ");
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = console.nextLine();
            if (Objects.equals(name, "Alienware")) {
                System.out.println("Вы выбрали" + computer1);
            } else if (Objects.equals(name, "MSI")) {
                System.out.println("Вы выбрали" + computer2);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Вы выбрали" + computer3);
            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Общая масса компьютера: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая масса компьютера вычисляется в методе `Computer::weight`, но проблема в том, что у этого метода есть входной параметр (как у сеттера), с именем, совпадающим с названием поля `weightComputer`.  То есть, в контексте данного метода существуют две вещи: *локальная переменная* и *поле объекта* с одинаковым названием `weightComputer`.  Чтобы их различать, необходимо использовать ключевое слово `this`, обозначающее ссылку на текущий экземпляр класса, то есть `this.weightComputer` будет относиться к полю текущего экземпляра.

Без явного указания такой ссылки присваивание `weightComputer = ...` произойдёт для этого входного параметра, а само поле останется неизменным.  Более того, после вычисления массы результат будет потерян, так как метод `weight` всегда возвращает 0.

Поэтому достаточно переписать данный метод *без входного параметра* в следующем виде:

```java
public double weight() {
    return this.weightComputer = processor.getProcessorWeight() + 
            memory.getMemoryWeight() + storage.getStorageWeight() + 
            screen.getScreenWeight() + keyboard.getKeyboardWeight();
}
```

Соответственно, для вычисления массы и присваивания полю, этот метод нужно где-то вызвать, например, из соответствующего геттера, который обеспечит "ленивое" вычисление массы, и вместо прямого обращения к полю следует использовать данный геттер:

```java
public double getWeightComputer() {
    if (this.weightComputer == 0.0) {
        return weight();
    }
    return this.weightComputer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  "\n" + "Производитель компьютера: " + vendor +
            "\n" + "Название компьютера: " + name + "\n" + "------------------------------------" + "\n" +
            "\n" + "Процессор" + "\n" + "------------------------------------" + processor +
            "\n" + "Оперативная память"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + memory +
            "\n" + "Накопитель информации"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + storage +
            "\n" + "Монитор"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + screen +
            "\n" + "Клавиатура"+ "\n" + "------------------------------------"  + keyboard +
            "\n" + "Общая масса компьютера: " + getWeightComputer() + "\n";
}
```

---

Также в методе `Main::main` цикл как таковой не используется.
Если выводится только один некоторый компьютер, можно использовать `switch` для более лаконичного кода:

```java
// ...
System.out.println("Введите компьютер который выбрали: ");
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
Computer computer = switch(console.nextLine()) {
    case "Alienware" -> computer1;
    case "MSI" -> computer2;
    default -> computer3;
};
System.out.println("Вы выбрали" + computer);
System.out.println("Общая масса компьютера: " + computer.getWeightNumber());
```